# Kubernetes Cluster- Worker node error while using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have created a Kubernetes cluster with 2 nodes, one Master node and one Worker node (2 different VMs).

The worker node has joined the cluster successfully, so when I run the commanad:
`kubectl get nodes` in my master node it appears the 2 nodes exists in the cluster!

However, when I run the command `kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml` from my worker node terminal, in order to create a deployment in the worker node, I have the following error:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused. - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Any help what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have issue with your `kubeconfig` file, as usually `localhost:8080` is the default server to connect in absence of this file . Generally, Kubernetes uses this   [file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/)  to store cluster authentication information and a list of contexts to which  `kubectl`  refers when running commands - that's why `kubectl` can't work properly without this file.

To check the presence of kubeconfig file, enter this command: `kubectl config view`.

Or just check the presence of the file named `config` in the `$HOME/.kube` directory, which is the default location for `kubeconfig` file.

If it is absent, you would need to copy the config file to your node, e.g.:

```yaml
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config 
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
sudo service kubelet restart
```

It is also possible to generate config file in a more difficult way - instead of copying - as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts).

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it is to copy the config from master node usually found here : /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf , to whetever node you want to configure kubectl ( even on master node) . The location to be copied is : $HOME/.kube/config

Also, you can this command from master node by specify nodeselector or label.

[Assign POD node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea, your `admin.conf` contains a default admin group. Pasting this on a worker node would grant more rights to a worker than necessary which in turn is a security flaw.